# git pull is failing with error: cannot fork() for git-upload-pack

Tags: linux, git, ssh

I'm just trying to do a git pull from my linux server (over SSH) - it was working earlier today, now it's giving me this:

```
fork: Resource temporarily unavailable error: cannot fork() for
git-upload-pack: Resource temporarily unavailable fatal: The remote
end hung up unexpectedly
```

Edit: top shows that I have plenty of spare CPU and MEM...

Edit: OK it turns out there were hundreds of ghost ssh-agent processes running on the server, mostly owned by the git user. Once I killed them, everything started working again. I've voted to re-open this question because I couldn't find any good information on this solution when searching for my problem - perhaps this could help others?

Comment: Sounds like your server is low on resources. :-(

Comment: I've now solved my problem - see my edit. Please vote to reopen this question if you feel it may help others.